# share_open_graph is not taking dynamic OG tags link or image

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

The code snippet below certainly works when manually specifying OG tags in the head. But when dynamically creating the tags via the share_open_graph method in the JS SDK, the dynamic image or link is not taken by the share dialog.

Is share_open_graph is deprecated or how to achieve this?

```
var FBDesc = "Test description";
var FBTitle = "Test Title";
var FBLink = "http://facebook.com";
var FBPic = "http://lorempixel.com/1200/630/sports/1/";

FB.ui({
  method: "share_open_graph",
  action_type: "og.shares",
  display: "popup",
  action_properties: JSON.stringify({
    object: {
      "og:url": FBLink,
      "og:title": FBTitle,
      "og:description": FBDesc,
      "og:image": FBPic
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: That is correct, you can not set these values dynamically any more. (The only context in which that is still possible, is when a _page_ shares a link, and has previously claimed ownership of the domain of that link.) If you want to share content with dynamic OG data - then you have to write a script on your server, that based on parameters it gets passed, dynamically renders the OG tags, so that Facebook can request them via a specific, parameterized URL.

Comment: Be aware though, that you have to set `og:url` to that same URL including the parameters. And that will make them different Open Graph objects, meaning all shares/likes will be split between those individual URLs.

Comment: Script based on parameters can be a good solution. Thanks for your comment @CBroe

Comment: Could @CBroe send me some reference for `The only context in which that is still possible, is when a page shares a link, and has previously claimed ownership of the domain of that link.` please :)

Comment: @EduardVoid https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v12.0/page/feed#custom-image